# Expose an OAUTH protected API via Azure API Management and perform delegation

Tags: oauth, identityserver4, azure-api-management, delegation

We have a .NET API running in Azure as an AppService. This API requires you to present a valid OAUTH access token. There is also an internal website using the API. Nothing special. The token is created using Identity Server 4 which externalizes the authentication to ADFS via WS-Federation.

Now, we want to expose the API to external consumers. These external entities are member of the AD domain and should authenticate using the same Identity Server + ADFS combo. But, we also want to allow some management, throttling, subscription keys, that sort of thing.

We are looking into Azure API management to do this but are having some difficulty with security. Mostly, the endpoints that Azure API management allows you to configure are actual services in their own right. They have a client ID that is different from the ClientID used by our API, at least, we believe it should.

So, the Api Management service receives a call with a token, but, that token cannot be used to call the downstream API that we want to manage. We believe the OAUTH on-behalf-of flow should be used for it.

Does API Management support that flow? We see a lot of samples where the actual API that you are exposing via API management basically allow anonymous calls.

How would one normally configure Azure API Management to do this? We are not willing to remove any security configuration from the API itself obviously.

Thanks! Looking forward to learning a bit more!

Answer (score 0):

The OAuth 2.0 settings available on an APIM instance are used by the developer portal when testing APIs on it.

The actual (pre-)validation of tokens is performed by the [`validate-jwt` policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#ValidateJWT), whose configuration for issuers, required claims, audiences, etc. should match your token requirements.

In the absence of the `Authorization` header, you would just have to redirect users to the login page (and set the redirect url accordingly back to APIM)